# Add values of the repeating words and plot them

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, count, bar-chart, unique

```
word                  
steam               84
heating              9
horizontal well      4
electromagnetic      2
single well          1
steam                5
foam                 2
heating              1
solvent              5
hexane               7
steam foam           1
surfactant         106
miscible             1
```

How can I uniquely print an output such that the values for repeating words add up and the words dont repeat

```
steam               89
foam                 2
heating             10
horizontal well      4
solvent              5
hexane               7
electromagnetic      2
steam foam           1
surfactant         106
single well          1
miscible             1
```

Comment: This is in Pandas dataframe format

Comment: `df.sum(level=0)`

Comment: `groupby() and sum`

Answer (score 1):

#### Setup

```
s = pd.Series(
    [84, 9, 4, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1, 5, 7, 1, 106, 1],
    ['steam',
     'heating',
     'horizontal well',
     'electromagnetic',
     'single well',
     'steam',
     'foam',
     'heating',
     'solvent',
     'hexane',
     'steam foam',
     'surfactant',
     'miscible']
).rename_axis('word')

s

word
steam               84
heating              9
horizontal well      4
electromagnetic      2
single well          1
steam                5
foam                 2
heating              1
solvent              5
hexane               7
steam foam           1
surfactant         106
miscible             1
dtype: int64
```

---

#### `sum`

```
s.sum(level=0)

word
steam               89
heating             10
horizontal well      4
electromagnetic      2
single well          1
foam                 2
solvent              5
hexane               7
steam foam           1
surfactant         106
miscible             1
dtype: int64
```